# How to test if the influence (coefficient) of a explanatory variable have changed over time?

Tags: regression, logistic, statistical-significance, regression-coefficients, structural-change

I have data for five different elections and want to test if the influence of campaign spending on the electoral result has increased or decreased from one election to another.

I am running a linear regression with the same dependent and independent variables (B1, B2, B3, B4, B5) for each of these elections and want to test if the coefficient of the independent variable B1 for the election X is statistically different from the coefficient of the independent variable B1 for the election Y.

Besides the difference, I also need to figure out which coefficient is higher in a statistically significant manner.

Could someone help me find out the best way to test this difference?

Answer (score 1):

I would estimate a single model for both elections and add interactions between the variables of interest and an indicator (dummy) variable for the latest election. The interaction effect tells you how much the effect of your variable is stronger or weaker in the latest election, so the test that most software packages print next to it is the test of the null hypothesis that there is no change in effect between elections.

Answer (score 0):

In linear regression (when there are no endogeneous errors) coefficients should be normally distributed in the limit by CLT, hence one very simple suggestion - to look at confidence intervals for corresponding coefficients and see if they are overlapping. If they don't then there is a significant difference.

Comment: That way you ignore the covariance in the sampling distribution of both parameters. So I don't think that that is a good idea.